# How can I bulk delete Menu Itemes in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, navigation

is it possible to bulk delete and bulk edit menu items in Drupal 8?

Question for Drupal 7: [Any way to bulk delete menu items?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62850/any-way-to-bulk-delete-menu-items)

Comment: I did some searching and found no contributed modules currently for Drupal 8 that do this. There is always the option to edit the database directly.  Kind of a bummer, makes menu editing a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bulk delete

there is module https://github.com/robdecker/menu_delete which you can use that provides checkboxes for easier delete of menu items.

its at the time of this writing missing a SELECT ALL feature which would make it even more helpful

its proposed to be included in core but there is no sign that it will https://www.drupal.org/node/2772961

so you can install it and take advantage of it using following commands

```
cd modules
git clone https://github.com/robdecker/menu_delete.git
drush en menu_delete -y
```

and then go into your menu and you should have available checkboxes and `delete selected` button

### Bulk delete alternative process

```
1. create a custom menu
2. edit items that you want to delete and try to put them under 1 parent (or few parent items)
3. edit those parent menu items and reassign them to the custom menu 
4. delete the custom menu
```

### Bulk edit

For bulk edit the https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_editor module is not yet ported to drupal 8 but it will be a good candidate if it gets ported

Answer (score 2):

[Menu Delete module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_delete) is now available for modern Drupal (Drupal 8 and Drupal 9)!